# Positioning a button using CALayer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-graphics, core-animation

I added an image button into the interface builder and I want to position it using CGPointMake so I added the button IBOutlet into the .h file and then added a CALayer in the .m file, here is my code...
in .h file

```
// This is the .h file
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
   IBOutlet UIButton *thebtn;
}
```

in .m file

```
// This is the .m file
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   CALayer *btn = thebtn.layer;
   btn.position = CGPointMake(480, 150);
   btn.opacity = 0.4f;
   [self.view.layer addSublayer:btn];
}
```

So that is great but my issue that the button position is not changing but the button opacity was changed so how can I fix that issue?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there any reason for you to use the layer instead of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the following:

First, move your code to `viewDidAppear`. Get rid of the `layer` code. Also, add `setNeedsLayout` call. Here is an example:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear 
{
    thebtn.center = CGPointMake(480, 150);
    thebtn.opacity = 0.4f;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

**UPDATE**

I figured out what the problem was. You have to turn off "Auto-Layout". After that your view will be repositioned to where you want.

Please see [this link to see how to disable `Auto Layout`](http://www.raywenderlich.com/17811/how-to-make-a-simple-mac-app-on-os-x-10-7-tutorial-part-13/smat-disable-autolayout)

Hope this helps!

Comment: it shows me this error (No visible @interface for 'View Controller'...)

Comment: Can you share your project with me? It'd be easier if I debug it on my end.

Comment: I uploaded it on dropbox here is the link 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yllm2ia7t5l78wq/Position%20a%20custom%20btn.zip

Comment: Hi @KevinMartin, I figured it out. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! I disabled Auto Layout and it worked with the CALayer too

Answer (score 1):

I think for such purposes as changing position and opacity of a view, you'd better operate with a `UIView` object (`UIButton` in your case), instead of its `CALAyer` property. This should work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   thebtn.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
   thebtn.alpha = 0.4f;
}
```